# Backbone/JavaScript ignore new objects

Tags: rest, model, backbone.js

Backbone seems to ignore the `new` operator. In the following code, the stock depends on a different product for each call. Backbone's first call is a `POST` — the model does not exist — but following are `PUT` even if a `new StockModel` is created each times. Are backbone's model singleton?

```
if (validName && validPrice) {
    this.collection.create({ 
        name: name.val(),
        price: price.val()
    }, { success: function(product) {
        var stock = new StockModel();
        var productId = product.get('id');
        stock.setProduct(productId);
        stock.set({ quantity: 10 });
        stock.save();
    }});
}
```

Stock is a resource like: `/product/{id}/stock`

My mistake; the error is at this line (setting the productId in the `stock.set` method seems to disorder Backbone):

```
stock.set({ id: product.get('id'), quantity: 10 });
```

If I replace the previous by the following, all is ok:

```
stock.set({ id: 0, quantity: 10 });
```

`product.get('id')` is an int

Comment: Are you sure thats not POST to the collection and then multiple PUT to the collection (for each new model)

Comment: I've got this problem for a couple of day. So yes, I'm sure this code attempt one POST and then PUT the following values. The var stock seems to be the same. I'm using RequireJS for module loading, but I don't see this can be related.

Comment: I've edited the question with further informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that you are using `id: product.get('id')` as the stock item's `id`.  Backbone uses `id` to determine weather something is a new object or not.  I'd rename this to `productId: product.get('id')`.  It's hard to tell exactly from the code snippet above exactly what you are doing, but I suspect that this is the problem.  Leave `id` out of it on initial save, and let your server assign it properly.  If you return the stock object from the server, backbone should sort it all out for you.

Hope this helps!